# .htaccess url rewriting any url based on length of url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm attempting to rewrite all all urls that are 4 exactly characters but allow other urls to be rewritten to it's name +.php

```
domain.com/a4Lv/ to domain.com/file.php?id=a4Lv
domain.com/longerThan4Chars/ to domain.com/longerThan4Chars.php
```

Is rewriting based on length possible?

Comment: It's a regular expression, anything is possible :)

Comment: @andrewtweber so in essence i can just do something like `RewriteRule /(....)/ file.php?$1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. I prefer to specify which characters are allowed (first option) but if you want to allow anything, use the second

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]{4})(/?)$ /file.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.{4})(/?)$ /file.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Breakdown:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]  limits it to letters and numbers
{4}          the length of the id
(/?)         optional trailing slash
```

Comment: I forgot about the second part of your question, but basically you can just then rewrite `(.*)` to `$1.php`. Since the previous rule has the `[L]` flag, that means this will only affect things that are not exactly 4 characters long

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can craft regular expressions to handle the number of characters in a match:

```
# for exactly 4 characters:
RewriteRule ^(.{4})/?$ /file.php?id=$1 [L]

# for more than 4 (need to exclude things ending with php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.{4}[^/]+)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```